# How do I set the height of a parent to auto minus pixels?

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

Consider the following :

CSS :

```
#parent {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

**GOAL :**  I want to hide the bottom 20 pixels of `<div id="child"></div>`.

**RESTRICTION :**  I can't know the height of `<div id="child"></div>` beforehand.

**PROBLEM :**  If I can't know the height of `<div id="child"></div>` beforehand how can I set `<div id="parent"></div>` to be 20px shorter than `<div id="child"></div>`?

**RESTRICTION :** I don't want to use JS to get the height `<div id="child"></div>` once it's been created and then set the height of `<div id="parent"></div>` to that height minus 20px. I know this is the obvious solution but there are too many occurrences of the above issue on my site to having to execute the relevant JS every time.

Thank you in advance for your help! :-)

Comment: why do you not want to use JS? actually, i don't think you'll have a choice if you don't know the height of the element you want to hide the bottom 20px of...

Comment: I basically find it kind of sloppy to use JS to work around that but I guess I'll have to if there's no other way. It'd be cool if CSS was that smart though, so that you could do something like `height : auto - 20px;`. Maybe in the future they'll add that who knows..

Comment: "Too many occurrences of the above issue on my site to having to execute the relevant JS every time" -- since these elements are IDs, "Too many occurrences" = once per page load, which is no big deal.

Comment: They're actually classes which makes it easier to target them and then apply the JS so I'll consider that even though I didn't want to :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.  Use `position: relative` to shift the `#child` element down by 20px;

On the `#parent` element, add `margin-top: -20px` to get the content's top edge to align to the
top edge of the parent block.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#parent {
    overflow: visible;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    margin-top: -20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#child {
    border: 1px dashed green;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed purus odio, ornare et neque in, sollicitudin ornare erat. Sed vel nisl vehicula, tempus nulla non, sodales orci. Pellentesque aliquam porttitor euismod. Nam imperdiet sit amet lectus sed vulputate. Sed varius vestibulum urna, quis consequat arcu mollis sed. Aenean pulvinar a magna non cursus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin elementum ipsum urna, non viverra nisi congue ut.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a genius! That's what I meant : Sometimes if your CSS is clever enough you can avoid writing JS. :-)